# How to implement iron-list lazy-loading with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lazy-loading, polymer-3.x, iron-list

I want to implement lazy-loading with iron-list. I am using typescript for my application. I found theshold example. But it is not working with typescript. The event is not triggered when scroll down. It is triggered when click on list item. How to implement when scrolling down?. My iron-list is some part of the page so when scroll down to end of the list I want to add more result from server

```
<iron-list .items=${this.items} as="item" scroll-target="scrollTheshold">
     <template>
           <div>content here.....</div>
      </template>
  </iron-list>
<iron-scroll-threshold id="scrollTheshold"  lower-threshold="200" on-lower-threshold="${this._loadData()}">
  </iron-scroll-threshold>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping iron-list from iron-scroll-threshold?

<iron-scroll-threshold id="scrollTheshold"  lower-threshold="200" on-lower-threshold="${this._loadData()}">

<iron-list .items=${this.items} as="item" scroll-target="scrollTheshold">
     <template>
           <div>content here.....</div>
      </template>
  </iron-list>
  </iron-scroll-threshold>

Comment: @Priyalal Koggalage Yes I checked above scenario also. But not working

Comment: Can you please try calling your function as on-lower-threshold="_loadData()" and check whether it hits? And is your items populates to the list? Is your list element reaching the given lower threshold value?

Comment: on-lower-threshold="_loadData()"  in this way function not triggered

Comment: @DRK  the usage in javascript is : `on-lower-threshold="_loadData" ` instead of  `on-lower-threshold="_loadData()" `

Comment: @HakanC yes but I am using typescipt, How to use it in typescript?

Comment: try arrow function:  on-lower-threshold="${() => this._loadData()}"